# How to receive array of objects as parameters in Python Flask passed as HTTP request using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, python, arrays, ajax, flask

My ajax call looks like this:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "/doSomeCoolThingOnServer",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: {
      simple_string: "Variable sent from client side",
      array_of_strings: ["John", "George"],
      array_of_objects: [
        { city: "Shanghai", population: 1000 },
        { city: "Budapest", population: 2501 }
      ]
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log("===== SUCCESS =====");
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
      console.log("===== ERROR =====");
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
```

I am trying to receive the **array of objects** as an array of dicts on Python, but I am returned with an **empty array**.

```
@app.route("/doSomeCoolThingOnServer", methods=['POST'])
def doSomeCoolThingOnServer():
    simple_string = request.form['simple_string']
    array_of_strings = request.form.getlist('array_of_strings[]')
    array_of_objects = request.form.getlist('array_of_objects[]')

    print(simple_string) #returns desired string
    print(array_of_strings) # returns desired array
    print(array_of_objects) # returns empty array
```

Please advise how to receive array of objects as parameters in Python Flask passed as HTTP POST request using AJAX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could serialize your objects using `JSON.stringify` and deserialize then on the server with `json.loads`. This effectively sends your array of objects as array of strings.

Serialize for ajax call:

```
array_of_objects: [
    JSON.stringify({ city: "Shanghai", population: 1000 }),
    JSON.stringify({ city: "Budapest", population: 2501 })
]
```

Deserialize on server:

```
import json
array_of_objects = request.form.getlist('array_of_objects[]')
print([json.loads(s) for s in array_of_objects])
```

Another option is to serialize the entire array instead of every array element separately. This sends the array of objects as a single string:

```
array_of_objects: JSON.stringify([
    { city: "Shanghai", population: 1000 },
    { city: "Budapest", population: 2501 }
])

import json
array_of_objects = request.form['array_of_objects']
print(json.loads(array_of_objects))
```